# Automatic Defect creation from ReadyAPI

Tags: soapui, alm, ready-api

I am working on ReadyAPI, and want to know whether defects can be raised automatically in HP ALM from ReadyAPI when the script fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is a REST API in ALM that you can use:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.60/api_refs/REST/Default.htm#REST_API/Getting_Started.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____3

The nice part about it being webservice based, is that you may then create the defects using normal Rest Request Teststeps.

Answer (score 0):

There are REST API's by microfocus that can be integrated to your ReadyAPI Project as answered by @Steen. However integration isn't that easy as there are no handy documentation.Apparently a whole lot of groovy Script needs to be written in your ready API project to ensure the defect creation and defect management is done appropriately.

You may try a Trial version of dragonfly that does readyAPI - HPALM integration pretty well.If it does the job the way you want you may go for paid version.

https://www.agiletestware.com/dragonfly